# How to import a Stata file directly from dropbox

Tags: database, stata, dropbox

I have Dropbox Plus installed both as an App and online. It turns out that I have very big data to handle and cannot store them in the App, otherwise a lot of memory would be lost. Instead I can sync them only online and have them stored in the dropbox servers.
Now, the problem is that I need to use those dta files directly from dropbox.com which apparently is not as easy as I was thinking. My naive approach was simply to copy paste the link provided by dropbox.com:

`use "https://www.dropbox.com/s/cxmbo2gsw8yuoic/pcs.dta",clear`

however it did not work. Does anyone know how can I do that in Stata please?

Comment: The internet does not work the same way as a file system. Stata cannot read/write a file over HTTP. You can download the file from Dropbox within Stata and then read it. But then you are back at having the file stored on your computer. Somehow you need Stata to run in the same environment as where the data is stored.

Comment: I see...so no workarounds on that (e.g. zipping it or storing in a less heavy format?)? The error is actually "file https://www.dropbox.com/s/9gb1n9m9cvf31n5/mol_ctry48.dta?dl=0 not Stata format" and when I try typing the file is, in fact, a messy file

Comment: That URL is not a file. That URL is a webpage that has some code that tells your browser to start downloading a file. This is not what Stata expects when you use the `use` command. Stata cannot read .zip files without extracting first. Similar to that Stata can't read a file over the internet without downloading it first. If you can open the file on any system you can try to run the command `compress` and save the file. Type `help compress` to read about that command.

Comment: To be clear, you can pass a URL in `use` but then you need a URL that return a Stata dataset and not instructions to a browser, the way Dropbox does. And the dataset is nevertheless downloaded to your computer when you do that, as in order for Stata to read a dataset if first needs to be on your computer. If you download it manually yourself first or let Stata do it to a temporary folder first, does not make a difference on your disk space requirements.

Comment: Well, one difference is that if you have many dataset but only need one at the time, then downloading in a temporary folder one at the time saves some disk space, but you would have to download the data from Dropbox each time you re-run your do-file. Seems unpractical with a very large file.

Comment: Cross-posted at https://www.statalist.org/forums/forum/general-stata-discussion/general/1670602-directly-importing-from-dropbox-com It is helpful to be told about cross-posting, and discourteous not to tell us.

Comment: @TheIceBear Your comments seems to be the basis for a fine answer.

Comment: @NickCox I did not know that when I started to type. :)

Comment: Sorry for cross-posting